# mysql select all from today up until now

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time

I'm trying to build a query where it will return all rows from today's date, but only up to this point in time of the day.

E.G.

If it's 12.30pm, I'd like it to return all rows with the date from 00:00 to 12:30 on today's date, but nothing after 12:30, or whatever time is when the scrips is run

Comment: What have you tried? What does your table look like that you will be querying?

Comment: can you post your table structure ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DATE(expression) removes the time and NOW() includes the current time:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE iDate > DATE(NOW()) and iDate < NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date < TODAY && date > DAYBEFORE
something like this should work fine for timestamp saved dates. Not sure about DATE formated values

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a starting timestamp and an ending timestamp:

`where created >= timestamp_start && created < timestamp_end`

Note that my answer assumes you're using some server side programming language to run these sql queries, and thus you would be passing a variable into timestamp_start and timestamp_end. time format: use Unix Timestamp